# WPF Custom control with textbox doesnot update from viewmodel changes

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I have a accustom control bound to a model class. So if any change in UI for textbox it updates ViewModel.model instance. but it doesnot work the other way. What is the necessary thing I need to look for? or troubleshoot steps pls.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the model?

Comment: Might be the [Binding Mode](http://geekswithblogs.net/mamta_m/archive/2010/07/04/wpf-binding-mode.aspx), but its hard to say without you posting ANY code.

Comment: I did have the Inotify implemented and binding mode is not a problem cause it updates ViewModel from control but not the other way

Answer (score 0):

You mean the value is displayed in the Textbox but a new typed value isn't?
If so you need to set two way binding on the Textbox binding:

```
<Textbox Text={Binding myTextProperty, Mode="TwoWay", UpdateSourceTrigger="ProprtyChanged"/>
```

This will enable both read & write functionality to your binding.

As @Ganesh says, you also need to make sure you're implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your `ViewModel`.

Comment: I did implement INotify on the model. Also Twoway is also enabled but the property I am binding to is a custom dependency property.